# Update TextView after a specific interval inside a Childfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to make a card that contains a fragment having multiple textViews which will show the frequencies of cores of CPU. The problem I am facing is that I cannot update the TextViews without effecting the whole Activity's performance. I tried using handler's postdelayed to call the functions needed to update the Views but it is also freezing the whole UI for that specific Interval.
Here are my code for the activity and the two fragments.

Parent Fragment

```
package com.psychokernelupdater.frags;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.psychokernelupdater.R;

public class TunerMain extends Fragment {

    public TunerMain() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tuner_main, container, false);
        Fragment cpu = new CPUFreq();
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.cpuFreqFrag, cpu)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();

        return view;
    }

}
```

Child Fragment

```
package com.psychokernelupdater.frags;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.psychokernelupdater.R;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CPUFreq extends Fragment {

    static float[] freq = new float[8];
    TextView[] C = new TextView[8];
    float[] fre;
    String[] curFreq = new String[8];
    String units, f;
    String[] cpuData;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    int delay = 500;

    public CPUFreq() {
    }

    public static float[] getCPUFrequencyCurrent() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            try {
                freq[i] = readSystemFileAsInt("/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu" + String.valueOf(i) + "/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                freq[i] = -1;
            }
        }
        return freq;
    }

    private static int readSystemFileAsInt(final String pSystemFile) throws Exception {
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            final Process process = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"/system/bin/cat", pSystemFile}).start();

            in = process.getInputStream();
            final String content = readFully(in);
            return Integer.parseInt(content);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }

    public static final String readFully(final InputStream pInputStream) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final Scanner sc = new Scanner(pInputStream);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            sb.append(sc.nextLine());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cpu_freq, container, false);

        C[0] = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CPU0);
        C[1] = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CPU1);
        C[2] = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CPU2);
        C[3] = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CPU3);
        C[4] = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CPU4);
        C[5] = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CPU5);
        C[6] = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CPU6);
        C[7] = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CPU7);

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                cpuData = updateFreq();
                updViews(C, cpuData);
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }, delay);

        return view;
    }

    public String[] updateFreq() {
        fre = getCPUFrequencyCurrent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (fre[i] == -1) {
                curFreq[i] = " OFFLINE";
            } else {
                if (fre[i] < 1000000) {
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###");
                    f = df.format(fre[i] / 1000);
                    units = " MHz";
                } else {
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
                    f = df.format(fre[i] / 1000000);
                    units = " GHz";
                }
                curFreq[i] = f + units;
            }
        }
        return curFreq;
    }

    public void updViews(TextView[] Arr, String[] cpu) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            Arr[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "CPU " + Integer.toString(i + 1) + " : " + "</b>" + cpu[i]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Please tell me how can I achieve this updating, without freezing the whole UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default handler is created on the same thread. You need to create a new thread with a handler, like this:

```
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("background");
Handler handler;
```

In your `onCreateView` you can now launch your code like this:

```
thread.start();
handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper())
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        cpuData = updateFreq();
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updViews(C, cpuData);
            }
        });
        handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```

Pay attention that views are updated in `runOnUiThread`, otherwise you'll get an exception, because views can be only updated in UI thread.

Also don't forget to stop your thread in `onDestroyView`:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    thread.quitSafely();
}
```